# Enclosing a particular element(s) in a vector in quotes

Tags: r, paste

I need a hint on how write

```
> paste("",0.125, "=", "T", sep="")
```

in order to output

```
"0.125" = "T"
```

instead of

```
"0.125=T"
```

Comment: Not easy to find but `?Quotes` givel lots of useful info about various ways to quote things in R

Answer (score 1):

You can get literal double quotes by using single quotes to wrap:

```r
writeLines(paste0('"', 0.125, '"', ' = ', '"', "T", '"'))
#> "0.125" = "T"
```

Created on 2018-06-30 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `cat` function , you can do this via this hackish way:

```
cat('"0.125"' ,"=", '"T"')
```

**Output:**

```
#> cat('"0.125"' ,"=", '"T"')
#"0.125" = "T"
```

If you choose to ignore single quotes inside cat function around decimal and T then it will not print the quotes.

so, `cat("0.125" ,"=", "T")` will produce output without quotes.

```
#> cat("0.125" ,"=", "T")
#0.125 = T
```